# (localDB)\Projects or (localDB)\v11.0

Tags: visual-studio-2012, sql-server-2012

I installed VS2012, SSME 2012 with localdb, and I discovered that I have 2 servers that I can connect to: (localDB)\v11.0 and (localDB)\Projects.

Which of them do I have to use for execising, what are them both for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This explains the difference and some issues to watch out for

http://aeronaught.wordpress.com/2012/11/22/vs2012-localdb-v11-1-v11-0-automatic-instance-horror/

Not sure on the difference but you should be using

(localdb)\v11.0

Answer (score 5):

I know I am bit late. But I am facing the same question now and found the answer. Thought I should share the [Answer](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/dfbac61b-ef09-4c06-98b2-bcb1c8c627f8/localdbprojects-and-localdbv110?forum=ssdt):

> (localdb)\Projects is the SQL Server Express LocalDB instance which is used by SQL Server Data Tools by default to host the sandbox databases created for your database projects (*.sqlproj) to enable F5 deployment and debugging.
>
> (localdb)\v11.0 is the generic SQL Server Express LocalDb instance which gets created when LocalDB is installed, and this is also used by other Visual Studio projects like the ASP.NET projects.
>
> See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh510202.aspx for more information on LocalDB

**Update**

Starting from EntityFramework 5.0, the default sql server is the your localdb\vxx.x instance now.

Comment: From link:

**(localdb)\Projects** is the SQL Server Express LocalDB instance which is used by SQL Server Data Tools by default to host the sandbox databases created for your database projects (*.sqlproj) to enable F5 deployment and debugging.

**(localdb)\v11.0** is the generic SQL Server Express LocalDb instance which gets created when LocalDB is installed, and this is also used by other Visual Studio projects like the ASP.NET projects.